# ASP.net web app, push notification to browser by creating a service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, web-services, push-notification

**Web application Asp.net & C#**

I am developing an web application that ideally would include a notification service, updates a user when they received an interest or a like on a browser.

**Theory**

For example user 1 clicks like for user 2, and user 2 information gets passed into my web application for processing. If I wanted to update user 2 when online/offline I need to have a process handle that asynchronously. When user 2 signs on, my application would have to check if there are any updates and push, and continue to check while the user is on. The way I see it is I would need to dedicate a task for each user that accesses my app to check if there are any updates for that user. If there aren't any updates, that task will be locked waiting for one. There will already be concurrent connections waiting for that task so that is 2x the consumption.

**Issue**

I am trying to figure out another approach to distribute that load so that my application can handle pushes gracefully by communicating with other systems or services. Since dedicating a worker task for each user with a concurrent connection would be too resource intense.

**Researched so far**

I looked into a message queuing system to see if that would solve the problem, but when researching it seems like I would be doing the same thing as dedicating a task to handle each user who access my application to listen to any messages coming from the queue.

Or even worse I would have to create unique queues for each user which is not recommended and then process the message and add more logic to whether the user is online/offline.

**Question**

What is the most efficient way of checking for an update, is it the way I described above, dedicating a task for each user uses my web application, or is there another design pattern that can be used to service that part of my application?

**Point I would like to make**

I don't have an issue with connecting the client to my web application with frameworks like signalr, or methods like commet or long polling.

I used signalR with SQLdependancy but there is issues with performance. I cant use SQL Server to trigger events because if the amount of users grow it locks up a thread on my server because each hub created with a dependency on SQL will call a asych/await. In theory I really want to replicate that as a service to my app, but am at a loss on figuring out how to that.

Comment: I think you might have been too quick to discount SignalR just based on what you read without really analysing your current setup.  See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance.  Also, I can see this as being closed as the question is either too broad, or would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: I can't see how it's opinion based I am clearly asking how push notification would work internally using services on the .net framework. As I said at the end, I am not struggling with connecting the browser/client to my web application, SignalR is great but alone it doesnt solve my problem. How does SignalR make a difference of what notification gets pushed to who when users are not connected? I need to program unique payloads, and updates also store unique information. SignalR is just a communication channel, it doesn't solve my issue on how does my application get serviced.

Comment: Just to conclude I love signalR and in noway did I mean it was a performance bottleneck itself, you can scale it and do awesome things with it. I just said it was a performance issue with SQLdependancy and sql acting as a service broker. A performance issue to SQL server, not my app. Doing a lot of research it really isn't a good idea to push any information to app or client that way. While looking for an alternative way, It just keeps getting increasingly difficult to find a good approach to solve my issue on pushing updates to my web app without causing a wreck.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar case:

In my apps I have many clients, each client can login more than once.  e.g. clients A & B,  client A1 login using a pc desktop browser, and at the same time login using Android phone(let's call it A2).  Client B2 login using iPhone, same client B1 pc desktop browser is offline.

Then, when A1 send a message to B (don't know B1 or B2):

1. A1 call Web Services or webapi in the IIS to send the message and store the message in sql.
2. A1 call the signalr Server, telling the Server that there is a message from A to B.
3. signalr Server knows that currently A1, A2, B2 are online, so the Server call A2 and B2 signalr client to update the client page.

here suppose A2 Android App. is in the foreground and is chatting with B, the screen will be updated to synchronize with A1.

here suppose B2 iPhone App. is in the background, a local notification will be generated and the hidden screen will be updated while the signalr message is received, and B can see the updated message when he click the notification.

4. When B1 login using pc browser some time  later, it calls the webservices or webapi to get latest messages.

that's it.  I don't have sql trigger, everything is idle when there is no new messages, except the signalr's heartbeat(only happens when connection state changes).

the design idea is that I tried to put loading on the client side and the clients are receiving messages at the earliest possible time.

Comment: In a scale out scenario how do you get client A1 on server A to talk to client B1 on server B without having a signalR server. Having signalR inluded in your application instead of another server. Your example is great I was just wondering how that particular scenario could be accomplished because I am really considering using signalR to lessen the headache. But that scenario is the one I need to work with if I do use it. I saw one of the developers Power Point and he said a server posts to another server using a information on clients connections saved to the database. How is that achieved?

Comment: If you consider the signalr server in my example as Server X, my webservices is actually in Server Y, and my ms sql Server is in Server Z.  In my case Server X can call Server Y's functions by webservices or webapi.  If you want Server Y to access Server X(in my case I don't need to do that), you need to add a console or Winform signalr client in Server X, and add a signalr Server in Server Y.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-502 if you Fast Forward to 56:30, there really is little to no examples using that scenario, which would ideally be the best Scenario in my case if I choose to add more functionality using singalR and then end up scaling out. The idea is to post to different http end points based on the server the user is connected to. It would be interesting to see how well that performs.